# A single die is rolled seven times. Find the probability that 2 appears at most twice.

Tags: probability

A single die is rolled seven times. Find the probability that 2 appears at most twice.

here we rolled die in 7 times so $n(s)=6^7$

from here how to processed

Comment: What it means is that out of the 7 times you roll the die, you get 0,1, or 2 two's.

Comment: "At most twice" means you see "2" on the die 0, 1, or 2 times in those 7 rolls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_0$ be the event that 2 doesn't appear at all, $A_1$ be the event that 2 appears exactly once and $A_2$ be the event that 2 appears exactly twice. The probability you need to calculate is the probability that $A_0\cup A_1\cup A_2$ occurs. Note that these events are clearly disjoint, so by additivity of the probability measure, we have:
$$\mathbb{P}(A_0\cup A_1\cup A_2)=\mathbb{P}(A_0)+\mathbb{P}(A_1)+\mathbb{P}(A_2)$$
Now it is easy to see that the desired number is $\frac{5^7+7\cdot 5^6+\binom{7}{2}\cdot 5^5}{6^7}$.